# Apple WWDC 2010 - software used for presentation

Tags: presentations

Wondering which software Apple have used to create presentation slides for WWDC 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [Keynote](http://www.apple.com/iwork/keynote/).

Wikipedia mentions:

> Keynote began as a software program for Apple CEO Steve Jobs to use in creating the presentations for Macworld Conference and Expo and other Apple keynote events

This cites O'Reilly's article on [Mac Dev Centre](http://macdevcenter.com/lpt/a/3099/)

> Keynote is Apple's $99 answer to Microsoft's PowerPoint. Jobs has been using early versions of Keynote at the MacWorld keynotes for over a year. Jobs explained that, "Keynote was built for me.

Comment: Do you have references on that?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately I cannot find any references. Given that it's an Apple application, I assume that's what Jobs will use.

Comment: I highly doubt it's Keynote, otherwise Apple would give a word about it, also as a promo to their app.

Comment: @Michael - it is Keynote. Updated with the references